# sox fails to split files

Tags: sox

According to the manpage (where it had been listed as an example) the following command should split input file to multiple audio files at points with 2 seconds of silence. Instead of that it creates only one file which is reported to be about 0.2 second long.

```
$ sox -V3 infile.wav  outfile.ogg  silence 1 0.50 0.1% 1 3.0 0.1% : newfile : restart
sox: SoX v14.3.1
sox INFO formats: detected file format type `wav'

Input File     : 'infile.wav'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 32000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
Endian Type    : little
Reverse Nibbles: no
Reverse Bits   : no


Output File    : 'outfile001.ogg'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 32000
Precision      : 16-bit
Sample Encoding: Vorbis
Comment        : 'Processed by SoX'

sox INFO sox: effects chain: input      32000Hz 2 channels
sox INFO sox: effects chain: silence    32000Hz 2 channels
sox INFO sox: effects chain: output     32000Hz 2 channels
```

Simpler examples using only trim gave me the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the following command should split input file to multiple audio files at points with 2 seconds of silence

Your command's arguments (1 **0.50** 0.1% 1 **3.0** 0.1%) tell sox to find at least 0.5s gap before and 3.0s gaps after sound. If you would like to detect 2s gaps you should use "1 0.50 0.1% 1 **2.0** 0.1%" (or similar) as parameters. You get short empty file because "newfile : restart" command is run at the end of the file.