# Trying to Split Wav file into two pieces with SoX

Tags: split, wav, sox

I'm trying to split one .wav file into two pieces where there is a few seconds of silence. Based on the documentation I've found, the following should work:

```
 sox testfile.wav tester.wav silence 1 0.50 0.1% 1 1.0 0.1% : newfile : restart
```

"testfile.wav" is a voice recording and I put about 4 seconds of silence right in the middle of it to test. The expected result is that I would get "tester001.wav" and "tester002.wav" from running this. Instead I get one file - "tester.wav" which is the first part of the original file (right up to the silence). I'm wondering how to make it continue and make a new file from the part AFTER the silence.

I found this: [sox fails to split files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210582/sox-fails-to-split-files) on StackOverflow, but the accepted answer to that question did not change it for me (changing the seconds to 3.0 gave me the same results, since I have a four second gap. It still didn't give me the second audio file.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Ha! Well it turns out the version of SoX that was running on my server was ancient, which was the problem. After updating to the current version, all works as expected. :)

Comment: What OS are you using? I've version 14.2.0-6 on a RedHat Linux server and I want to upgrade it to the latest one. Can you guide how can I do it?
Thanks