# How to crop wav file in python without opening it?

Tags: python, audio, wave

I have a VPS with low virtual memory. When I try to crop wav file using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367691/1402321, I get out of memory error. Is there a way to crop wav file without read whole file into memory?

Comment: try this : https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html#wave.Wave_read.readframes

Comment: @AkshayTilekar why not make that an answer iso a comment?

Comment: @xtofl done...........!!

Comment: microscope : did this solved your problm ??

Comment: I'm microspace, not microscope. :-), but that will do

Comment: @microspace LOL, AutoSpell did that :-)