# Creating python list in R via reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I would like to split a wave file using python via `reticulate` in R, a sample script is extracted from [Python, How to split a .wav file into multiple .wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999150/python-how-to-split-a-wav-file-into-multiple-wav-files)

```
 from pydub import AudioSegment
    t1 = t1 * 1000 #Works in milliseconds
    t2 = t2 * 1000
    newAudio = AudioSegment.from_wav("oldSong.wav")
    newAudio = newAudio[t1:t2]
    newAudio.export('newSong.wav', format="wav")
```

I did similarly using R as below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reticulate)
use_python('/usr/bin/python3',required = TRUE)
py_config()
pydub.py <- import('pydub')
time.start <- as.numeric(data.df.st02[loop,'time_start'])*1000
time.end <- as.numeric(data.df.st02[loop,'time_end'])*1000
new.audio <- pydub.py$AudioSegment$from_wav('142533.wav')
```

But returned the following error:

```
> new.audio[1:2]
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Can anyone enlighten me on how to write `[t1:t2]` in R?

Comment: "I did similarly using R": please share all the code you used.

Comment: certainly @nicola

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python subset operator is a wrapper of the `__getitem__` method and the `:` is a wrapper to create a `slice` object. You have to import the `builtins` module. Try this:

```
require(reticulate)
use_python('/usr/bin/python3',required = TRUE)
pydub.py <- import('pydub', convert=FALSE)
pybuiltins <- import_builtins(convert=FALSE)
new.audio <- pydub.py$AudioSegment$from_wav('142533.wav')
#important: time.start and time.end must be integer
time.start <- as.integer(1*1000)
time.end <- as.integer(2*1000)
#create a slice object
sl<-pybuiltins$slice(time.start,time.end)
new.audio_split<-new.audio$`__getitem__`(sl)
new.audio_split
#<pydub.audio_segment.AudioSegment>
```