# Cut a wave format audio file based on start and end time

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have an Audio file which is in wav format. The length of an audio file (considering) is of 120sec, i.e. 12000ms.

I have dictionary of start and end time as `{'start': 2432, 'stop': 6732}, {'start': 10676, 'stop': 18716}`. I have to slice this particular amount of time from the same 12000ms audio file. Finally I have to save it to two .wav files in a folder. Is there any python library or function on any code so I can use it easily to integrate into my project. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999150/python-how-to-split-a-wav-file-into-multiple-wav-files/43367691

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, How to split a .wav file into multiple .wav files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999150/python-how-to-split-a-wav-file-into-multiple-wav-files)

Comment: [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/AudioClip.html#audiofileclip) can work also with audio files. It uses `FFMPEG` library/program so probably [pyffmpeg](https://mhaller.github.io/pyffmpeg/) or [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python) should also do this

Comment: yeah i found the solution. how can i save those in folder iteratively. my question is not completely solved. Thanks