# Make chunks in Audio files with overlap in python

Tags: python, audio, chunks, segment

I want to make chunks from my audio files in order to overlap between chunks. For example if each chunks has 4 second length and first chunk start from 0 to 4 and step for overlapping is 1 second, second chunk should be start from 3 to 7.According to this [How to splice an audio file (wav format) into 1 sec splices in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799902/how-to-splice-an-audio-file-wav-format-into-1-sec-splices-in-python)
 ,I used `pydub` module for doing this and `make_chunks(your_audio_file_object, chunk_length_ms)` method, but it doesn't have overlap between chunks and just slice an audio file into fix length chunks. Anyone has an idea for this purpose ? Thank you

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: sorry, i was late. yes it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

frequency, signal = wavfile.read(path)

slice_length = 4 # in seconds
overlap = 1 # in seconds
slices = np.arange(0, len(signal)/frequency, slice_length-overlap, dtype=np.int)

for start, end in zip(slices[:-1], slices[1:]):
    start_audio = start * frequency
    end_audio = (end + overlap)* frequency
    audio_slice = signal[int(start_audio): int(end_audio)]
```

In essence, we do the following:

1. Load file and it's corresponding frequency. For the sake of example I assume its single channel, with multi-channel it would work all the same, just more code.
2. Define desired slice length and overlap. The array will give us start of every audio piece. By zipping it a step further and adding overlap we get desired chunks.

To convince yourself that slicing works, check this snippet:

```
slice_length = 4 # in seconds
overlap = 1 # in seconds
slices = np.arange(0, 26, slice_length-overlap, dtype=np.int) # 26 is arbitrary

frequency = 1
for start, end in zip(slices[:-1], slices[1:]):
    start_audio = start * frequency
    end_audio = (end + overlap) * frequency 
    print(start_audio, end_audio)
```

Output:

```
0 4
3 7
6 10
9 13
12 16
15 19
18 22
21 25
```

Comment: what is "audio[start_audio: end_audio]"? isn't it signal?

Comment: How is this supposed to change when the frequency is not 1? print(start_audio, end_audio)

Comment: tnx but i wish the code could save the obtained music chunk