# How can I deactivate OpenAI Whisper's normalization for audio input longer than 30 secs? (transcribing filler words)

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, openai-whisper

OpenAI's Whisper delivers nice and clean transcripts. Now I would like it to produce more raw transcripts that also have filler words (ah, mh, mhm, uh, oh, etc.) in it. The post here tells me that it's possible by setting the normalization to false: https://huggingface.co/spaces/openai/whisper/discussions/30

I managed to use this code, however I only get whisper to transcribe 30 seconds. How can I make it process a longer audio files?

Please note that I'm a total beginner with whisper as well as python.

What I've done so far: I mainly use the code from https://huggingface.co/spaces/openai/whisper/discussions/30 Since I don't want to use a dummy dataset, I load my local mp3 with librosa. I guess there are also other ways to do this and I'm open for it.

As I understand it, instructing the whisper processor is necessary for deactivating the normalization. Thus, not whisper is used here (`import whisper`) but whisper via `transformers`. The relevant switch is `normalize = False`.

My code (myscript.py):

```
from transformers import WhisperProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration
import librosa

speech, _ = librosa.load("myaudio.mp3", sr=16000, mono=True)

processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-large")
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-large")

model.config.forced_decoder_ids = processor.get_decoder_prompt_ids(language = "de", task = "transcribe")
input_features = processor(speech, return_tensors="pt", sampling_rate=16000).input_features 
predicted_ids = model.generate(input_features)
transcription = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids, skip_special_tokens = True, normalize = False)

print(transcription)
```

This works fine so far. However, only the first 30 seconds are transcribed.

Transcription of longer audio files should be possible with `pipeline`, as mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-base):

> The Whisper model is intrinsically designed to work on audio samples of up to 30s in duration. However, by using a chunking algorithm, it can be used to transcribe audio samples of up to arbitrary length. This is possible through Transformers pipeline method.

According to this webpage, the code for this is

```
import torch
from transformers import pipeline
from datasets import load_dataset
device = "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
pipe = pipeline(
  "automatic-speech-recognition",
  model="openai/whisper-base",
  chunk_length_s=30,
  device=device,
)
ds = load_dataset("hf-internal-testing/librispeech_asr_dummy", "clean", split="validation")
sample = ds[0]["audio"]

prediction = pipe(sample.copy())["text"]

# we can also return timestamps for the predictions
prediction = pipe(sample, return_timestamps=True)["chunks"]
```

Now I'm having trouble combining my code with this code. How do I load my local mp3 instead of the dataset? (librosa doesn't seem to work here.) Where can I set normalization to false?

Comment: Hey there, were you able to make this work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It might even not be possible. I'm not quite sure what normalization does. It might be it only adds grammar and such, but doesn't remove filler words. Those might not even be there in the raw transcript.

Answer (score 0):

To run the OpenAI Whisper pipeline with your local file, simply use `prediction = pipe("myaudio.mp3")` (assumes `audio.mp3` is in your working directory.

Looking through the `pipeline()` docs, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to pass `normalize = False` to the underlying processor.

You could dig deeper into the `pipeline()` class to do some custom hacking that gives you access, or you could revert to your initial approach using the `WhisperProcessor` and `WhisperForConditionalGeneration` classes for the transcription.

With this approach however, you'll need to split your audio into 30 second chunks yourself (since this function comes bundled in with the `pipeline` class which you're not using since it doesn't let you set `normalize = False`).

There's information on splitting audio files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999150/how-to-split-a-wav-file-into-multiple-wav-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799902/how-to-splice-an-audio-file-wav-format-into-1-sec-splices-in-python).